# Disable mouse over scroll in autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a list like the scrollable result example.

Link: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#maxheight

[image]

In this example, when we place the mouse on the last option, the scroll bar automatically descends. I would like to disable this, is it possible?

I tried to apply events directly to the list items but I wasn't successful, I imagine I'm going to the wrong place.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a feature of your Browser. When I follow the steps you described, I am not able to replicate the issue. a CSS Height value is set for the drop down options, this causes the browser to render scroll bars based on the Overflow styling. Nothing in the demo is set to autoscroll.

Comment: @Twisty what is your browser? The point is this:

https://i.imgur.com/7ZdAhP6.gif

Comment: When I tested, I was using Firefox 119 on Windows 11.